# need help with a translation from a song - 'yo le entro al pulquito'

Tags: traducción, letras-de-canciones

i'm currently working on a song in spanish, yo soy el adventurero por pedro fernandez

the paragraph that has the line is this

> Yo juego baraja y sé parrandear Lo mismo les tomo tequila o mezcal Yo
> le entro al pulquito, también al champagne Lo mismo les bailo que
> tango, que un vals Lo mismo un jarabe que algún chachachá

anyway i'm not understanding

'le entro al pulquito'

i think it's a reference to pulque which is a mexican drink, but i don't understand this sentence.

bonus points if you can help me understand

'lo mismo les tomo tequila'

what does the les here do?

thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

["Entrarle a algo"](https://dle.rae.es/entrar) is a colloquial verb phrase meaning to be able to eat or drink or to start eating or drinking something. In Argentina it can also be used to mean "f***ing somebody":

-- ¿Le entrás (a X persona)? (Also: ¿Le das (a X persona)?)

-- Sí, le entro / le doy.

The closest meaning DLE provides is:

> entrarle a algo
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. El Salv., Méx. y Ur. Acometer una empresa.

"Pulque" is a Mexican alcoholic drink, "pulquito" being its diminutive. "Le entro al pulquito" would thus mean "I can drink pulque". The underlying idea can be that drinking pulque requires some courage, or that the guy in question is open to different alternatives. This would be in line with the title of the song.

As regards "les tomo tequila", "les" is a dative referring to plural "you" indicating that the guy can drink tequila for the others' benefit, or if the others request so. This use of the dative is also colloquial and, in my opinion, impossible to translate unless we use some phrase or clause.

In the singular, we would use "te" with the same colloquial register:

-- Te hago lo que quieras. (I can do anything you ask me to.)